# Gmail api create draft results in cant find GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

I keep getting this error and have looked everywhere and I cannot fix it. Can someone please hold my hand. I have downloaded the json filed and named it so it matches. I have watched every youtube video to make sure I created credentials correctly and also added my email as a test user. Not sure what to do at this point. I have json file and the token in my IDE, also I was able to log in and choose my username and got the flow message so everything seems to be working. Up until I copy and paste the create_email_draft from gmail api documents. Basically I just want to send some automated emails. Here is my code...let me know if you need anything else.

> ERROR:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\carlo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\quickstart.py", line 61, in 
> gmail_create_draft()
> File "C:\Users\carlo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\quickstart.py", line 25, in gmail_create_draft
> creds, _ = google.auth.default()
> File "C:\Users\carlo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\venv\lib\site-packages\google\auth_default.py", line 616, in default
> raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
> google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Process finished with exit code 1

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
import base64
from email.message import EmailMessage
import google.auth
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


def gmail_create_draft():
    """Create and insert a draft email.
       Print the returned draft's message and id.
       Returns: Draft object, including draft id and message meta data.

      Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
      TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
      for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
    """
    creds, _ = google.auth.default()

    try:
        # create gmail api client
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

        message = EmailMessage()

        message.set_content('This is automated draft mail')

        message['To'] = 'carlosmedina239@gmail.com'
        message['From'] = 'selenytesting123@gmail.com'
        message['Subject'] = 'Automated draft'

        # encoded message
        encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()

        create_message = {
            'message': {
                'raw': encoded_message
            }
        }
        # pylint: disable=E1101
        draft = service.users().drafts().create(userId="me",
                                                body=create_message).execute()

        print(F'Draft id: {draft["id"]}\nDraft message: {draft["message"]}')

    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        draft = None

    return draft


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gmail_create_draft()



def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    # You don't have to care about anything on top of this comment

    try:
        # Call the Gmail API
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
        labels = results.get('labels', [])

        if not labels:
            print('No labels found.')
            return
        print('Labels:')
        for label in labels:
            print(label['name'])

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have tried to copy the code from the quickstart without trying understanding what its doing.

Your `gmail_create_draft` method is not building the credentials properly.  So its looking for it in the default env var which you dont have set which is the cause of your error message.

I have tested this code and it works.

```
#   To install the Google client library for Python, run the following command:
#   pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib

from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
import base64
from email.message import EmailMessage
import google.auth
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    Lists the user's Gmail labels.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('tokenSend.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('tokenSend.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    # You don't have to care about anything on top of this comment

    try:
        # Call the Gmail API
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        message = EmailMessage()

        message.set_content('This is automated draft mail')

        message['To'] = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
        message['From'] = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
        message['Subject'] = 'Automated draft'

        # encoded message
        encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()

        create_message = {
            'message': {
                'raw': encoded_message
            }
        }
        # pylint: disable=E1101
        draft = service.users().drafts().create(userId="me",
                                                body=create_message).execute()

        print(F'Draft id: {draft["id"]}\nDraft message: {draft["message"]}')

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from gmail API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Results in

> Draft id: r4575751609218968324
> Draft message: {'id': '182fcd72a7a06a96', 'threadId': '182fcd72a7a06a96', 'labelIds': ['DRAFT']}

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your assistance but I copied and ran your code and it gives me error code    google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_scope: Bad Request', {'error': 'invalid_scope', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'})

Comment: I'm kind of a noobie might need extra help if not too much to ask =]

Comment: try deleting tokenSend.json The code should be working i ran it here.